# c++ storing values out of rage of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-debugging

```
char *asd = new char[5];
asd[10] = 'f';
```

Why does this code not give me a error when run whit debug?
It causes a crash during a release build.

Comment: (Bad) luck. There is absolutely no guarantee of any kind what will happen here, and crashing is about the best you can hope for, because at least then you spot the problem. If it looks like it kinda works some of the time, it's much harder to track down.

Comment: Rage of an array crashed your program.

Comment: @Tadeusz Kopec: I read this thrice before realizing that its 'Rage', not 'Range'!

Answer (score 5):

Because **undefined behavior** doesn't mean it has to crash.

It means *anything* can happen, including appearing to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::vector instead a regular array, because there is no boundary checks in arrays in C++ or C and it is by design (but you must use the at method). An array is just a ponter to the first memory address and you can use this to iterate but there is no runtime information about the boundary. A good case is strings: we use a \0 terminator for this reason.

about the debug:
when you run a c program with a debugger it is not 100% equal to run this program over the operational system only. threads are a good example, there is differences when you run over a gdb for example.

probably in a different machine or operational system it cannot crash. to avoid this you can use valgrind to watch the code, for example.

Comment: -1 because using a `vector` doesn't magically solve the problem. If you go outside the bounds of the vector, it's still undefined behavior. Plus the questions is why it works in debug and doesn't in release. He knows why it crashes.

Comment: vector::at can help to find the problem because it throw an exception in debug or runtime. there is no differente in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

asd[10] simply means "address of asd + sizeof(10 bytes)" Depending on which memory location is assigned to asd, this memory address might not be available for your program to use, leading to undefined behavior:

- No guarantee that any other variable will NOT overwrite asd[10]
- Application crash

Comment: "Depending on which memory location is assigned to asd, this memory address might not be available for your program to use, leading to undefined behavior" - actually, it's undefined behavior regardless of whether the memory is or isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you compile and run under debug there are some guard blocks implemented around an allocated space of memory, which the advanced compilers can check if it was overwritten or not, thus signalling you memory access errors.
When under release, there is nothing like this, depending where the compiler put your bytes you simply overwrite what's after, and that might be everything.
Some interested readings are: http://scottmcpeak.com/memory-errors/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faz3a37z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx